# Does Python change my byte string?

Tags: python, c, string, arrays

Does Python change my string??

[image]

The related question is [I was using a little shellcode in my python but failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125651/i-was-using-a-little-shellcode-in-my-python-but-failed)

PS: I was doubting what's is the end charecter of Python String or C string, if the string have the end charecter, how to deal with it? Does this related to this question?

Comment: Don't you think `\x49`   is the same as `I`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> chr(int('49', 16))
'I'
```

Actually, `\x49` *is* `I`.

---

A word of explanation about this:

`\x49` means "Char with code 49 in hex. 49 in hex is `int('49', 16)`: `73`. `73` is the ASCII character code for `I`, which you can verify with: `ord('I')`: `73`.

Comment: OK I got it. Can you explain what happend here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125651/i-was-using-a-little-shellcode-in-my-python-but-failed

Comment: @Eout Yes, please see the answer there : )